# Merge Two Sorted Lists Python

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm trying to solve merge sorted linked list problem.For that i've created three method. `addlast , print and merge` For linked list class created a three objects `obj and obj1 (To create two linked list)` Using `obj3` calling a merge method by passing both linked list head pointer.But here it only print `linked list 1` instead of both.

My expected result should be creating both linked list and print the sorted linked list.So what could be the reason the my code isn't working ?

```
class node:
def __init__(self,data) :
    self.data = data
    self.next = None

class linkedlist:
  def __init__(self) :
     self.head = None

  def addlast(self,data):
    newnode = node(data)
    if self.head == None:
        self.head = newnode
    else:
        current = self.head
        while(current.next != None):
            current = current.next
        current.next = newnode

  def print(self):
    current = self.head
    while(current):
        print(current.data, "-->",end="")
        current = current.next
    print("NUll")

  def merge(self,obj,obj1):
    current = obj.head
    current2 = obj1.head
    newnode = node(None)        
    while current and current2 != None:
        if (current == None):
            newnode.next = current2
            break
        if (current2 == None):
            newnode.next = current
            break
        if current.data <= current2.data:
            newnode.next = current
            current = current.next
            print(newnode.data)
            newnode = newnode.next
        else:
            newnode.next = current2
            current2 = current2.next
            print(newnode.data)
            newnode = newnode.next

        if current:
            newnode.next = current

        if current2:
            newnode.next = current2
        
    print(newnode.data)

obj = linkedlist()
obj.addlast(10)
obj.addlast(20)
obj.addlast(30)
obj.addlast(40)

obj1 = linkedlist()
obj1.addlast(50)
obj1.addlast(60)
obj1.addlast(70)
obj1.addlast(80)

obj3 = linkedlist()
obj3.merge(obj,obj1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

- You created `merge` as an instance method, but never use `self`. If the intention is to merge a second list into the current list (`self`), then you need only one argument, i.e. the "other" list, not two.
- `merge` should set the `head` attribute of the list that gets the merge result, i.e. `self.head` should be assigned a reference.
- `newnode` progresses through the merged list, but your code loses track of what was the first node of that merged list, so you need an extra name so that you can later assign to `self.head`
- `if (current == None)` is never going to be a true condition, as the `while` condition requires that *both* `current` and `current2` are not `None`. The same goes for `if (current2 == None)`: it will never be true.
- The code to link the only remaining list (the last two `if` statements) should be put *after* the loop, not inside it. Only after the loop it is certain that one of `current` or `current2` is `None`. Also that code can be simplified with the use of the `or` operator.
- The reason you only see part of the merged list printed, is that you don't print the nodes that are appended ("in bulk") in that last operation.

Here is the corrected code:

```
    def merge(self, obj1):  # Only need one argument, not two
        current = self.head  # Use self
        current2 = obj1.head
        dummy = newnode = node(None)  # keep track of this dummy node      
        while current and current2:
            if current.data <= current2.data:
                newnode.next = current
                current = current.next
            else:
                newnode.next = current2
                current2 = current2.next
            newnode = newnode.next  # This is common to both if/else case
 
        newnode.next = current or current2  # out of the loop
        self.head = dummy.next  # update current list's head reference
```

The calling code should have near the end:

```
obj.merge(obj1)
obj.print()
```

Answer (score 0):

This links the 2 lists Studrec and Aves then sort Studrec pulling the corresponding items from Ave.

```
def revert(Studrec, Ave):
    Studrec, Ave = map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(Studrec, Ave), key=lambda x: x[0])))
    return Studrec, Ave
Studrec, Ave = revert (Studrec, Ave)
```

Answer (score -1):

In the merge function you're not updating the self.head, instance variable your code is merging the list but you're not keeping track of the head. Modify your code merge function to point the self.head to new node:

```
  def merge(self,obj,obj1):
    current = obj.head
    current2 = obj1.head
    newnode = node(None)      
    self.head=newnode
```

Comment: You certainly don't want to set the head to a new node that has no data.